# What does this 'catch himself' mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> [While three children sneaking up a set of staircases to the third
>   floor under the Invisibility Cloak] They didn't meet anyone else until
>   they reached the staircase up to the third floor. Peeves [=a fairy]
>   was bobbing halfway up, loosening the carpet so that people would
>   trip. 
>       "Who's there?" he said suddenly as they climbed toward him. He narrowed his wicked black eyes. "Know you're there, even if I can't
>   see you. Are you ghoulie or ghostie or wee student beastie?" 
>       He rose up in the air and floated there, squinting at them. 
>       "Should call Filch, I should, if something's a-creeping around unseen." 
>       Harry had a sudden idea. 
>       "Peeves," he said, in a hoarse whisper, "the Bloody Baron has his own reasons for being invisible." 
>       Peeves almost fell out of the air in shock. **He caught himself** in time and hovered about a foot off the stairs. (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

Is it –– caught himself –– an idiom: it has the meaning ‘to hold oneself back abruptly from saying’ [in Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/catch-oneself)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, it means Peeves managed to stop himself from falling before he hit the floor.